# Como desactivar control version git en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, windows, github

Como desactivar control version git en `Android Studio` en Windows, lo que hice fue ir al menú:

`VCS` - `enable control version`

y ahora no se como deshacerlo, apagarlo, disable, turn off.

gracias

Answer (score 1):

En las versiones 3.0 o posterior de Android Studio ve a:

`File`  > `Settings` > `Plugins` y  `Version Control`, ahí selecciona el directorio que esta versionado y elimina el registro a GIT.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]